# "WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations" using flutter from VS-Code on a Mac

Tags: flutter

Since I installed Android-Studio on my Mac I get the following warning when I run a flutter app from VS-Code:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on macOS in debug mode...
main.dart:1
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:macOS, arch:arm64, id:00008112-001165280131401E }
{ platform:macOS, arch:x86_64, id:00008112-001165280131401E }
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:50612/Hg0-6cz5T04=/ws
```

The App runs normally thereafter.

I was looking for some configuration about the destinations in the flutter project. No success.

Any idea about that?

I tried all the "flutter clean / flutter build / flutter doctor" stuff.